# Specify angle in newdimen (tikz)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm using `newdimen` all the time, as it is easier to fine-tune a graphic.

However, I'm having troubles with defining an angle with `newdimen`. tikz complains if I leave a number without unit, and it does not accept `r` as the unit.

Is there a way to specify an angle with `newdimen`. I know we can do it by using `newcommand` or `def`, but `newdimen` would be much more elegant if it is possible.

Comment: Please provide us with the code that shows what you have tried. You can certainly convert a dimension to a number with `\pgfmathsetmacro`. Also you can use `trig format=rad`.

Comment: E.g. `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\newdimen\mydim
\mydim=60pt
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (\the\mydim:2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}` works.

Comment: As you are using `tikz` it may be better to declare dimensions using `\pgfmathsetlength{<register>}{<expression>}` see §94.1 of the manual

Comment: while it's possible it seems a rather unnatural thing to store an angle in a dimen, it isn't a length? Why not a newcommand?

Comment: Hi all, I see angle as a dimension in polar coordinates. I was looking for an easy fix, like extension (unit) for degrees and radians that `newdimen` would accept. If there is nothing like that,  I'll just keep using `newcommand` or `def` for angles.